# Why PHP IntlDateFormatter returns wrong date? +1 hour

Tags: php, date

When I try to format date from one timezone to same timezone I get wrong time (differenced by 1 hour). My code is:

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ru_RU',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Europe/Moscow'
);

$date = new DateTime("2015-07-29 14:00:00", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
echo $formatter->format($date);
```

Expected time is `14:00`, but `15:00` returns.

**UPDATE**: When I display year 2013 or 2014 everything is ok! What happens in 2015?

**UPDATE2**: +1 hour added from 26 october 2014. Its time when Russia goes to eternal winter time. Ok. But... how to format correctly?

Comment: What does `var_dump($date);` give? I cannot run it myself right now.

Comment: @alexn, `class DateTime#2 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2015-07-29 14:00:00"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Moscow"
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have same problem, update icu (International Components for Unicode) at your OS.

Answer (score 3):

I use directly 'GMT+03:00' instead 'Europe/Moscow'.
Apparently the developers of the library do not have time for lawmakers.

Comment: It is not good solution because there is winter/summer time in some countries.

Comment: Concretely in the 'Europe / Moscow' there is no division into daylight saving time.

Comment: Indeed `Europe/Moscow` has no this division but many others has. So this solution is not robust as using hardcoded values. Also, this solution depends on lawmakers, so what you will do if this division comes on? :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `php.ini` file for `date.timezone` and make sure its set to

`date.timezone = "Europe/Moscow"`

Comment: Yes, `"Europe/Moscow"` is set. Also, date_default_timezone_get() returns `"Europe/Moscow"`